# What is the right way of handling images for Android 7" and 10" tablets?

Tags: android, android-layout, responsive-design, drawable

I am working on an Android landscape oriented app targeting both 7 inch and 10 inch tablets. 
Only standard devices like Nexus, Galaxy tab, Sony and Asus tabs etc are targeted.
The UI for both the 7 inch and 10 inch devices are same.

Our current implementation is as follows.

We have two set of layout files (similar contents) in layout-sw600dp-land and layout-sw720dp-land folders.
Our designer has provided us with two set of drawables sliced for 7 inch and 10 inch devices.

These images are sliced from a PSD 3840 px wide for xxhdpi 10 inch and 3072 px wide for xxhdpi 7 inch.7 inch drawables are around 20% smaller than their corresponding 10 inch ones

All the drawables are placed in 4 density buckets without sw-xxxdp qualifiers. Instead we have appended an _s to the 7 inch drawables and use a them for layouts in sw-600dp(7 inch) devices.

1. Is there actually a need for separate drawables for 7 and 10" devices as the UI is the same ?
2. Is there any better way of handling drawables in Android for tablets so as to support all the devices ?
3. Currently we are testing on a 10 inch and 7 inch Galaxy tabs which are both mdpi. Is the above implementation stable and scalable ?

Answer (score 0):

1. Yes, there is such a need. I recently ran into this problem with devices that have the same density (mdpi in my case), but a screen size difference of over 200 pixels on each side, resulting in some UI elements just plain not fitting in the smaller resolution screen. If your UI is the same, the drawables that fit for 1280x800 might not fit for 1024x600, for example.
2. As far as I know, the `sw-xxxdp` approach is what works best. An alternative would be to pick or scale resources at run time, which will make rendering your screens noticeably slower.
3. It's really not that scalable at all, as you have to maintain separate sets of resources and take care of updating them properly. If you really want to go hardcore about it, consider writing a custom tool that manages your project's drawables. Not to go off on a tangent, but it could implement some simple versioning and warn you when instances of the same drawable in different folders are from different "design versions" so to speak.
   There might even be an open source tool for that already, but I haven't yet seen one.

Comment: Here's my current implementation. I have 3 set of folders for drawables. drawable, drawable-sw600dp-mdpi (x 4 densities), drawable-sw720dp-mdpi(x 4 densities) for phone, 7" and 10" tabs respectively. Total of 12 folders of images. but my 10" galaxy tab GT-P7500 (1280x800) seems to pick up images from sw720dp-XXHDPI folder instead of sw720dp-MDPI folder. However when i use only 1 set of folders without swXXXdp qualifiers its picking up correctly from DRAWABLE-MDPI folder . What could be the possible issue ?